# How to solve: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this action on a sealed instance

Tags: java, android, react-native, google-play-console, prelaunch

I'm getting this error in pre-lauch report and have looked everywhere on the internet but haven't found a solution. I'm not sure how to correct this error. Our application is written in react-native. Please I would really appreciate any help

**Error in Pre-launch report:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nuba.mobile.android, PID: 18007
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this action on a sealed instance.
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.enforceNotSealed(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2992)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setSource(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:818)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setSource(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:795)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.obtain(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:3008)
    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:7897)
    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:7883)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1051)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:876)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:199)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1225)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

**They tested it on this device for example.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCq1N.png)

**I have attached the logcat**
https://codeshare.io/78O6Z1

Comment: Did you learn anything else about this? I got the same error on the exact same test device. It looks like it crashed while in a `WebView`. The bot clicked a button that adjusted the website layout and this led to the crash: https://streamable.com/7k8irj

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find the problem?